# C++, template variable in non template class

Tags: c++, templates

I am using the following template classes:

```
template <class T>
class Point2D
{
    private:
            T x;
            T y;
...
};

template <class T>
class Point2D;

template <class T>
class Line{
    private:
          Point2D <T> *start;  
          Point2D <T> *start; 
    .... 
};
```

If I want to create an object Line, it is necessary to write type of the point and type of the Line

```
int main
{
     Point2DC<double> p1(0,0);
     Point2DC<double> p2(10,10);
     Line<double> l(&p1,&p2);
     ...
}
```

I find it rather pointless... If points are double, so Line must be also double... Is it possible to templatize only pointers in class Line and do not templatize all class, something like that

```
template <class T>
class Point2D;

class Line{
    private:
          template <class T>
          Point2D <T> *start;  
          Point2D <T> *start; 
    .... 
};
```

and use

```
int main
{
     Point2D<double> p1(0,0);
     Point2D<double> p2(10,10);
     Line l(&p1,&p2);
     ...
}
```

Comment: How is template class Point2DC defined?

Comment: There was an error, I fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

Not directly.  You can make a function `make_line` along the lines of `std::make_pair` that implicitly figures out the return type based on the input types, but its return type will still be `Line<double>`.  This is useful if you're constructing an anonymous `Line` for passing into another function.

In C++0X, there's a new use of the `auto` keyword for declaring an implicitly typed variable, based on the type of the assigned expression.

So this would allow to do something like this (without changing your `Point2D` or `Line` classes):

```
template <class T>
Line<T> make_line(Point2D<T> *p1, Point2D<T> *p2)
{
    return Line<T> (p1, p2);
}

template <class T>
void DoSomethingWithALine(const Line<T> &l)
{
     ....
}

int main
{
     Point2DC<double> p1(0,0);
     Point2DC<double> p2(10,10);
     // C++0X only:
     auto l = make_line(&p1,&p2);

     // Current C++:
     DoSomethingWithALine(make_line(&p1, &p2));
     ...
}
```

Comment: You may also want to look at how you're using Point2D and Line - there may not be any reason to make them templates, if you only ever use them with doubles.  You may be over-generalizing, and making things more difficult than they need to be.

Comment: Short example could be helpfull. Thanks.

Comment: Using auto in this example... Point should be float, double, short, int. Do you find reasonable to replace all these types with double and do not use templates?

Comment: The only real use of `auto` would be just the example I've already given.  If you really do intend to use `Point` for float, double, short, and int, then you really do need templates.

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice your code, my browser window is almost minimalized :-). For some calculations, I needed only a float, it is significantly faster...

Comment: Unless you really need the precision of a `double`, just use `float` and avoid the need for templates altogether.